# How do I display the full title bar in Firefox 29?

Tags: firefox

With Firefox 29, it no longer displays the full title. For example, in this screen shot here, it only display the beginning of "The New York Times - Breaking News, World News & Multimedia". How can I make it display the whole thing?

EDIT (for clarification): I'd like to see the full title of the web page of the tab I am on at all times (hovering the cursor would not work for me). Making the tab full width only works if I have 1 or 2 tabs, but most of the time I have many more tabs so this wouldn't work for me.

[image: NY Times page]

Comment: Moving your mouse pointer over the title excerpt doesn't count, does it?

Comment: Nope, although I should have made this clear...

Comment: title bar, or tab title? Or both?

Comment: There's [Tab Width](http://en.design-noir.de/mozilla/tab-width/) plugin, but I doubt setting a long width for all tabs will be practical.

Comment: @AthomSfere I'd like to see the full title of the tab I am on. I think it only makes sense with a title bar.

Comment: @DanielBeck Right. That wouldn't work.

Comment: Most of the browsers do this.  Although I admit more of the title should be shown since you only have one tab.  But this isn't exactly "new" behavior.

Comment: Also, for Windows, you can show the Title bar by typing `about:config` in the address bar, navigating to the **`browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar`** entry, and setting it to **false**.

Comment: @DanielBeck Hovering isn't a solution, particularly when you have lot of tabs. Instead of just a glance at the title bar, you have to locate the tab, move the mouse there and wait for the tooltip to appear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to the menu, and **Customise**.

At the bottom-left of the customisation menu is a toggle button labelled **Title Bar**.  This is the button you want.  (It reverts to old-style top-of-window layout.)

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/747791/245595) shows pictures of each menu.

Comment: Useful answer, but not perfect (that's Firefox' fault), as we loose the vertical space Firefox tried to gain by using the title space. Being side-by-side with the menu would be better.

Answer (score 5):

On the Firefox menu, click **View** > **Toolbars** > **Customize**; the Customize Firefox page appears.
At the bottom left corner of the Customize Firefox page click the **Title Bar** button. Clicking this button toggles the display of the Firefox title on the top-left corner of the browser window.